# How to autoplay a video on website load using HTML 5 in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

Google Chrome is not playing video automatically on webpage load.

```html
<video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/247833422.hd.mp4?s=8d872a36d3dbe7f74e9613ab144d088b5bab6649&profile_id=174" poster="" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
```

Looking for solution

Comment: Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange in general, do not use signatures in posts. Your user-card, which is displayed on the bottom right of every post you make serves that purpose. If you desire for your contact information to be public, then that can be in your profile page, to which your user-card links. Adding a signature to your post, as you did here, is often considered spam. Such signatures also tend to result in the post being more negatively received (i.e. tends to result in people downvoting and/or not upvoting).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the video even exists on that url; it's not showing up for me. If it does exist, however, then it might be that it is taking some time to load. As it loads, it will automatically start playing the video.